# .NET - Are there any flip clock controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, clock

For a .NET (Winforms) application are there any flip clock controls?

Ideally it would look something like the one found on the BlackBerry Bold:

[alt text http://images.crackberry.com/files/u3/reviewimages/blackberry9000c/lgclock3.jpg](http://images.crackberry.com/files/u3/reviewimages/blackberry9000c/lgclock3.jpg)

**UPDATE 1:**

Following this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535812/using-a-custom-wpf-control-in-winforms) link I have added an element host to my project to host the WPF retroclock that [@Shane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63477/shane-fulmer) mentioned.

**UPDATE 2:**

A few steps that I followed:

- Compile RetroClock
- Add DLL reference to WinForm App
- Add 'using WPFControls.Clocks;'
- Add 'elementHost' to Form
- In Form Load event add:

  `//create retroclock`

  `RetroClock rc = new RetroClock();`

  `//add retroclock to element host`

  `elementHost1.Child = rc;`

**UPDATE 3:**

Styling the clock

```
//style clock
rc.Height = 30;
rc.IncludeLeadingZero = true;
rc.IsAmPmVisible = true;
rc.FontSize = 60;
rc.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
rc.TimeFormat = TimeFormats.Hour12;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going along with Joel's answer, there's a simple one for WPF [here](http://rgramann.blogspot.com/2009/08/retro-flip-clock-wpf-control.html).

Comment: Thanks - I have decided to try and host it in my Winform App.

Answer (score 4):

That would be a little out of place for winforms, the main point of which is to expose the common controls to .Net to help developers build windows applications that use the "standard" look and feel.  This doesn't mean you won't find one, but that you should think 3rd party first here.  Anything provided by Microsoft is going to be at best an afterthought.

WPF, on the other hand, is a much better fit for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy to make one yourself.  Add a class, derive it from Control.  You'll need a Timer that keeps it going, have its Tick method call Invalidate().  Override OnPaint() to draw the digits and am/pm indicator.  You'll want the TextRenderer.DrawText() overload that draws inside a rectangle to get the digits centered.  Draw a black line through the center.

Ought to be fun.

Comment: Fun until the boss asks why you are building a clock...  : )

Answer (score 1):

There is a free UIElement
HandyControl
by Mahdi Hosseini
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MahdiHosseini.HandyControls

I hope it help.