# How do you add a non-default button to a winform

Tags: winforms, jbutton

Is there a way to add a good looking button to a winform that doesn't look like a default button?
I wanted to add something that looks like the java jbutton thingy, it's like a perfect rectangle, it's blue, and stuff like that.

I know you can change the color and font of a button, but it never looks right. So is there a different non-WPF way to change the skin or look of a button in a windows form?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to "skin" it, you could create an image the same size as your button and then set it using the BackgroundImage Property. Set the FlatStyleProperty to Flat.

You can end up with something like this:

[image: Example Button]

Alternatively, you could use an element host control to host WPF content in your WinForms app, as per this question: [Using a custom WPF control in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535812/using-a-custom-wpf-control-in-winforms)