# Canvas control is not available in Windows form application?

Tags: wpf, canvas

WPF Canvas control is not available in Windows form application. Am using Visual Studio 2010. Framework 4.0. Is there way to add these controls to VS2010 toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WPF Usercontrol containing the Canvas control and then host it in an [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control in winforms. Details of how to do it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754008.aspx).

You can then add that final control to the toolbox. More details on how to do can be found [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535812/using-a-custom-wpf-control-in-winforms).